# Jfree chart is not calculating the Y axis in case of line chart

Tags: java, graph, 2d, jfreechart

I am using jfree.chart for graph rendering. I am using the Line chart but it is rendering the graph properly and showing the Y axis as shown in the attached snapshot.
I am not sure what is this or why is this. But it seems that Y-axis is not calculating.
Please advice what possibly could there be missing that is leading to this.

Following is the snippet of the code:

case GraphType.LINE_CHART: 
case GraphType.SCATTER_PLOT: theCharts[0] = CreateLineChart(tsChartTitleStructure.GetText(), strXAxisTitle, straYAxisTitles[0], datasets[0], thePlotOrientation, bShowLegend); break;

Thanks
[image]

Comment: can you add some of your code? meanwhile I'll check my old Jfree chart code :)

Comment: case GraphType.LINE_CHART:
case GraphType.SCATTER_PLOT:
theCharts[0] = CreateLineChart(tsChartTitleStructure.GetText(), strXAxisTitle, straYAxisTitles[0], datasets[0], thePlotOrientation, bShowLegend);
            break;

Comment: not here plz, edit it in the question.

Comment: It looks like the data is missing.

Comment: Actually the jfree chart allow a null dataset. Even I have tried this in the test program and verify that even that case also the Y-axis will be caliberated properly. The graph does not look like this even when data is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. Wanted to share with you guys that it is the problem when we set the range of the graph.
In JFree chart there is a range that can be defined by Min and Max values. So in our case this range was 1 for Min and 1 for Max which was causing this problem.
So I think I have got the solution for this. So if there is some issue with the range set on the graph created in JFree, it could be helpful to look at the Min and Max values set as range on the graph.